# Ionic - Open external app with uri scheme using Deeplinks

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I have two ionic applications, and I want to navigate from app1 to app2. I have some example:

app1:

```
 openApp() {
       window.open("app2://myserver.com/?param1=111&param2=222", "_system");}
```

Then in the app2, I setup deep link for receive the params. It worked fine, but, unfortunately this seem like not open a new actual app, it open override into the current app1.
If I change the "_system" to _blank, it automatically add the "http" to the url, and it open an browser.

Is there any solution for this case. I want to open a new actual application that running parallel with the app1.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-launcher Could help you

Comment: sorry but I see that AppLaucher can only launch app with uri or package name, it can not launch an url scheme with parameter :((

Comment: are you using Cordova or Capacitor? 
use this plugin to receive URLs in your app: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks